# Crop image after taking image from camera

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My question is that I want to add crop image functionality in my pocketWallet app. I want to take image from camera and save it in ImageView after that i want to crop that image. I have read many questions like same but it Unfotunatly not found required answer.

Please tell me how can I change imageview size with exact image size that i take from camera.

I am using a uiview to crop the specific part of the image . But when I cropped the image then not get exact part which I want to crop. My cropped image code  is below,

```
-(UIImage *)cropImage{
    float tempx=CGRectGetMinX(cropedAngle.frame);
    float tempy=CGRectGetMinY(cropedAngle.frame);

   CGRect rect=CGRectMake(tempx, tempy, 320, 200);

    CGImageRef image = [imgView.image CGImage];

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image,rect);
    UIImage *imge = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    // Create and show the new image from bitmap
    return imge;
}
```

First of tell my logic is right or not to crop image? In which this code cropedAngle is my uiview which i used to crop the specific part of image .

Where am I wrong?